# How to add gzip support in Nginx for XHR type?

Tags: nginx, gzip

Google PageSpeed Insights is suggesting me to use gzip compression on a file `asyncload.php`.

Looking at the developer tool, the content that `asyncload.php` serving is under the `XHR` type.

I'm using Nginx and here are my current configuration for gzip support in `nginx.conf`.

```
gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 9;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_min_length 10;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/xhtml+xml;

# Disable for IE < 6 because there are some known problems
gzip_disable “MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)”;

# Add a vary header for downstream proxies to avoid sending cached gzipped files to IE6
gzip_vary on;
```

**My questions are:**

1. How do I add gzip compression on XHR type served via a PHP script?
2. Is there XHR fully support gzip compression on all browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my own solution.

Taking a closer look at the `Headers` of the file served, the Response Header is showing as `Content-Type:application/json`

I added `application/json` to the list of `gzip_types` directive, and it solves the problem.

Now the file served is gzip compressed, without PageSpeed Insights warning.